# Textarea not posting value in PHP

Tags: php, html, textarea

I am creating hidden textarea on my page, and after cloning my whole dynamic html page, I am populating the textarea with that cloned data. CLoned data contains the copy of the html page. My problem is the textarea is working for different different html pages but for one page textarea is not posting the value.

I have tried with some more online tools. And it was working there.

Here is my html that I am setting in textarea using jquery:

```
                <div id="index">
            <!------------- start calculator i/p section  ------------->
                <div id="algo_div">
                    <p id="algo_title">Expiration-Inspiration Ratio</p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p id="purpose"><strong>Purpose: </strong>To evaluate the ECG of a patient during inspiration and expiration.</p>
                </div>
            <style>
            .secondtd
            {
            padding-left:0 !important;
            padding-right:0 !important;
            }
            .secondtd input[type="text"]{
            width:60px;
            border:1px solid #999;
            height:20px;}
            .secondtd input.datepicker{
            width:80px;
            border:1px solid #999;
            height:20px;}
            .secondtd input[type="radio"]{
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right:0;}
            .secondtd .radio{
            display:inline-block;}
            /*.secondtd .radio span{
            margin-left:-3px;}*/

            .thirdtd input[type="text"]{
            width:60px;
            border:1px solid #999;
            height:20px;}
            .thirdtd .radio input[type="radio"]{
            margin-left:0;
            margin-right:0;}
            .thirdtd .radio{
            display:inline-block;}
            /*.thirdtd .radio span{
            margin-left:-3px;}*/



            </style>
                <p class="calculator_tab">Questions</p>
                <div class="page_content">
                    <div class="calculate_form">
                        <form method="post" name="input_form">
                            <table width="631px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody><tr class="ivar1">
                                        <td colspan="3" id="ittbl">
                                            <div id="inner_table">
                                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <caption id="caption_ivar1" class="tblcaption">longest R-R interval on expiration</caption>
                                                <tbody><tr id="tbl_tr1_ivar1"></tr><tr id="tbl_tr2_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c11">during expiration 1</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c12" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr3_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c21">during expiration 2</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c22" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr4_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c31">during expiration 3</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c32" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr5_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c41">during expiration 4</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c42" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr6_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c51">during expiration 5</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c52" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr7_ivar1"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar1c61">during expiration 6</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar1c62" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr>                                    </tbody></table>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="ivar2">
                                        <td colspan="3" id="ittbl">
                                            <div id="inner_table">
                                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <caption id="caption_ivar2" class="tblcaption">shortest R-R interval during inspiration</caption>
                                                <tbody><tr id="tbl_tr1_ivar2"></tr><tr id="tbl_tr2_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c11">during inspiration 1</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c12" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr3_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c21">during inspiration 2</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c22" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr4_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c31">during inspiration 3</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c32" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr5_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c41">during inspiration 4</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c42" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr6_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c51">during inspiration 5</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c52" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr><tr id="tbl_tr7_ivar2"><td width="300px"><div id="ivar2c61">during inspiration 6</div></td><td width="70px"><div><input disabled="disabled" value="" id="ivar2c62" class="wdth" type="table"></div></td><td width="121px">seconds</td></tr>                                    </tbody></table>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr></tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!------------- end calculator i/p section ------------->

                <div id="d1">
                    <div class="results">
                        <ul class="tabs">
                            <li style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(101, 186, 3);" id="li_result" class="active"><a href="#">Results</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div style="border-top: 3px solid rgb(101, 186, 3); background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="results_content">
                            <div style="display: block;" id="result_tab" class="tab_content tbcontent">
                                <div id="tbcontentd1">
                                    <p id="result_lbl"><strong>Result</strong></p>
                                    <table class="results_content conttbl" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody><tr style="display: none;" class="tr_ovar1 data_complete0">
                                                <td class="conttd" width="327px"><label id="lbl_tr_ovar1">Data complete?</label></td>
                                                <td class="conttd" width="130px">
                                                    <label id="ovar1" class="output">No</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="conttd" width="150px">
                                                    <label id="ovar1_label" class="output_lbl"></label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="tr_ovar2 data_complete1">
                                                <td class="conttd" width="327px"><label id="lbl_tr_ovar2">E-I ratio</label></td>
                                                <td class="conttd" width="130px">
                                                    <label id="ovar2" class="output">enter data above</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="conttd" width="150px">
                                                    <label id="ovar2_label" class="output_lbl"></label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table id="note_tbl" class="results_content conttbl" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>        
                                    <div id="caution">
                                        <p><strong>Caution:</strong> Any diagnosis, drug dosage, or significant result should be verified by a qualified health practitioner.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="result_action">
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please let me the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Isolate the problem into the shortest test case possible, work on that, if you then have a problem come back and ask with a succinct example.

Comment: PHP code would help. And  rewrite your question please... I don't get what you want to say with the cloning part.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Cups and tastro. This issue is resolved. Some inline css was creating problem.